# Arraylist to txt file

Tags: android

I have an app on the market that stores sensor data to a txt file, I do this by saving the sensor values to an arraylist and at the end of the session I write the files to a txt file. The customer wants an app that will do this for over an hour, I tried to run my app for an hour and it obviously crashed.

Should I constantly write the sensor data to the txt file? or should I write the data from the arraylist to the txt file every couple of minutes and then clear the arraylist?

Out of memory arraylist caused the crash

Comment: Can you provide more information on why your app crashed?

Comment: Given that the limitation is memory, then you should should write your data to the file periodically. You should consider having a pair of arrays. Sample your data into the first array. When you reach either a time or size threshold then stop sampling into the first array and start sampling into the second array. Use a background thread to write the first array to your file and then clear the array. Likewise when the next threshold is reached switch to the other array, etc. This will ensure that your sampling remains smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to display sensor data to the user, you could just write it directly as you receive it. Consider using a [BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) for this.

If you do need to have the n most recent samples accessible in your app, then consider an age-based cache where the sensors store data in the cache, and adding a new value when there are already n values in the cache causes the oldest value to be removed and passed to a writer.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way will be store data in real time on sqlite , then export or display data with simple filter.